# How do i pick file names with specified pattern in scala

Tags: regex, scala

```
OTC_omega_20210302.csv
CH_delta_20210302.csv
MD_omega_20210310.csv
CD_delta_20210310.csv

val hdfsPath = "/development/staging/abcd-efgh"
val fs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)

val files = fs.listStatus(new Path(s"${hdfsPath}")).filterNot(_.isDirectory).map(_.getPath)
val regX = "OTC_*[0-9].csv|CH_*[0-9].csv".stripMargin.r
val filteredFiles = files.filter(fName => regX.findFirstMatchIn(fName.getName).isDefined)
```

What is regex do i need to give if i need any file name that starts with either (OTC_ or CH_ ) and ends with YYYYMMDD.csv ?

As per the above files i need two outputs
OTC_omega_20210302.csv
CH_delta_20210302.csv

Please help

Comment: `"^(?:OTC|CH)_.*[0-9]{8}\\.csv$"`

Comment: @wiktor, Yes, This works, but what is the use of ?: here , also why \\. in the end , it works like this also ^(OTC|CH)_.*[0-9]{8}.csv

Comment: `.` matches any char other than a line break char. You must escape `.` to make it match a dot.

Comment: The `(?:...)` is a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions), it is used for alternatives or to quantify sequences of patterns. Since it does not cause memory allocation for submatches, it is better in this case than a capturing group.

Comment: Thanks for voting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```scala
val regX = "^(?:OTC|CH)_.*[0-9]{8}\\.csv$".r
val regX = """^(?:OTC|CH)_.*[0-9]{8}\.csv$""".r
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q0dz3j/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:OTC|CH)` - a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions) matching either `OTC` or `CH` char sequences
- `_` - a `_` char
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `[0-9]{8}` - eight digits
- `\.` - a literal dot (**note** `.` matches any char other than a line break char, you must escape `.` to make it match a dot)
- `csv` - a `csv` string
- `$` - end of string.